# Calculated Measure with parameter

Tags: iccube-reporting

I have Measures like revenue, count_clickouts, count_impressions etc. and I would like to create calculated Measures with these Measures in a fixed time range (e.g. revenue_last_year).
Of course I can create one calculated Measure per possible combination of Measure and time range, but is it possible, to create one calculated Measure with parameters both in the name and the definition.
I tried something like this:

```
with member [Measure].[@{measure}_last_@{time_unit}] as sum(@{time_unit}.last_member.previous_member,@{measure})
```

So far I couldn't make it work. Is there an option to do this at all, or is this not implemented? We use IcCube reporting 5.2.2.

Answer (score 1):

I use the [STATS] dimension for this, mostly for financial functions like [Prior Year], [Budget -/- Actuals], etc.

What you need to do is:

- Measure: count_clicks - this is the measure with data linked to TIME
- Then, create a one time [STATS] dimension, with [STATS] hierarchy.
  Next, define the members you want, like [Prior Year]

Here is an example in the Sales schema, which is included by default in each icCube installation:

```
 WITH CALCULATED MEMBER [Stats].[Stats-Time].[Prior Year] AS
 ([Stats].[Stats-Time].defaultmember, prevYear() ), SOLVE_ORDER = 1000

SELECT [Time].[Year].[Year] on 0
, {[Stats].[Stats-Time].[L-Stats-Time].&[Value], [Stats].[Stats-Time].[Prior Year]} on 1
FROM sales
WHERE [Measures].[Amount] * {[Customers].[Geography].[Region].[Europe].[Netherlands]}
```

Result:

[image]

The [Prior Year] will work with each Measure. Note to keep in mind the order sequence (SOLVE_ORDER) of the formulas.

Let me know if this works for you.